# Looping through a HashMap using iterator does not stop for an if condition

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, hashmap, iterator

A `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` has 10 entries but I only want to print 3 entries.

Code:

```java
HashMap<Integer,Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
hm.put(2, 1);
hm.put(5, 3);
hm.put(7, 2);
hm.put(4, 1);
hm.put(6, 3);
hm.put(8, 2);
hm.put(9, 1);
hm.put(3, 3);
hm.put(1, 2);       
hm.put(0, 2);
Iterator <Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> itr = hm.entrySet().iterator();
int n=4;
int i=0;
while(itr.hasNext()){
    if(i<n){
        Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = itr.next();
        System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" repeated "+entry.getValue());
    }
    i++;
}
```

Output

```
0 repeated 2
1 repeated 2
2 repeated 1
3 repeated 3 //program will wait for 2 or 3 seconds here
4 repeated 1
5 repeated 3
6 repeated 3
7 repeated 2
8 repeated 2
9 repeated 1
```

Expecting output:

```
0 repeated 2
1 repeated 2
2 repeated 1
3 repeated 3
```

Why is the if-condition inside while-loop is not working?

Comment: Hint: Print `i` inside of your loop. What do you think is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't exit out of the loop once `i` becomes 4. Also, you don't consume/read the subsequent elements from the iterator as `itr.next()` is inside the *if* block. So, it keeps incrementing `i` until it overflows to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (-2147483648) and this takes a few seconds (which you have observed).

At this point the condition of the *if* block becomes true (`i < n`) and hence it starts printing the other elements from the iterator.

You can print the value of `i` to see this.

```
System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" repeated "+entry.getValue() +". The value of i is: " + i);
```

Prints,

```
0 repeated 2. The value of i is: 0
1 repeated 2. The value of i is: 1
2 repeated 1. The value of i is: 2
3 repeated 3. The value of i is: 3
4 repeated 1. The value of i is: -2147483648
5 repeated 3. The value of i is: -2147483647
6 repeated 3. The value of i is: -2147483646
7 repeated 2. The value of i is: -2147483645
8 repeated 2. The value of i is: -2147483644
9 repeated 1. The value of i is: -2147483643
```

Comment: Please help me understand why it keeps incrementing until it overflows to Integer.MIN_VALUE (-2147483648)?  instead of Integer.MAX_VALUE(2147483647) as we are adding(++) , not subtracting(--)

Comment: @user2817235 `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE`

Answer (score 1):

When `i` reaches `n` the `if` condition will become `false` and `i` will be incremented indefinitely whereas the iterator will not step to the next. At some point `i` starts to be smaller than `n` due to number overflow (but a lot of while iterations are passed without going to the next in the meantime) and then your loop ends in an undesired manner. You will need

```
} else {
    itr.next();
}
```

or change somehow the condition of your loop so it will not continue its work when it no longer makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You must move out of if the iter.next(), so the solution is:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
HashMap<Integer,Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
hm.put(2, 1);
hm.put(5, 3);
hm.put(7, 2);
hm.put(4, 1);
hm.put(6, 3);
hm.put(8, 2);
hm.put(9, 1);
hm.put(3, 3);
hm.put(1, 2);       
hm.put(0, 2);
Iterator <Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> itr = hm.entrySet().iterator();
int n=4;
int i=0;
while(itr.hasNext()){
       Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = itr.next();
    if(i<n){
        System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" repeated "+entry.getValue());
    }
 
    i++;
}
  }
}
```

OUTOUT is:

```
0 repeated 2
1 repeated 2
2 repeated 1
3 repeated 3
```